# How to have multiple JW players on same page

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

JS Fiddle of what's happening

https://jsfiddle.net/n1tvx49x/1/

I don't have `id` attribute. Will it work without that. With `id` its working fine.

Here is my following HTML. It consists of outter `figure` tag and inside that there is `div` tag and inside that  have another `div` tag with `class="jw-player"`.

**I can't change my HTML**

```
<figure data-embed-type="jwplayer" data-embed-url="video-url1" data-embed-loaded="false">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
    <div data-embed-url="video-url1" class="jw-player"></div>
  </div>
</figure>

<figure data-embed-type="jwplayer" data-embed-url="video-url2" data-embed-loaded="true">
  <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
    <div data-embed-url="video-url2" class="jw-player"></div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

I want to embed JWPlayer videos inside both of these divs. `$node` has the `figure` element whole.

```
    var videoObject = $node.querySelector('.jw-player');      
    var playerInstance = window.jwplayer(videoObject);
    window.player1 = playerInstance;
    playerInstance.setup({
      file: 'video-url1',
      mediaid: 'asd34',
      image: 'jpg-url1'
    });
```

and another

```
  var videoObject = $node.querySelector('.jw-player');
  var newplayerInstance = window.jwplayer(videoObject);
  window.player2 = newplayerInstance;
  newplayerInstance.setup({
    file: 'video-url2',
    mediaid: 'asder3',
    image: 'jpg-url2'
  });
```

I am getting only one JW Player on my screen. Because the second one is also replacing the first div only. And 2nd div is not getting changed. And when I am comparing the two instances on console, I am getting result as equal.

`player1 === player2
true`

Comment: how are you assigning $node ?

Comment: You can see jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/n1tvx49x/1/

Comment: Well that's a bummer. It looks like without a id its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an ID using JavaScript before creating the player.

```
var videoObject = document.querySelector("div[data-embed-url='video-url1']");
videoObject.id = "player-1";
var newplayerInstance = window.jwplayer(videoObject);
window.player2 = newplayerInstance;
newplayerInstance.setup({
  file: 'video-url2',
  mediaid: 'asder3',
  image: 'jpg-url2'
});

var videoObject = document.querySelector("div[data-embed-url='video-url2']");
videoObject.id = "player-2";
var newplayerInstance = window.jwplayer(videoObject);
window.player2 = newplayerInstance;
newplayerInstance.setup({
  file: 'video-url2',
  mediaid: 'asder3',
  image: 'jpg-url2'
});
```